# Is not getting child by name (as3 flash)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
    private var childrenOnStage:Number;



    public function Main() 
    {


        //iniation players
        character = new player();
        character.name = "player";
        timmy = new SirTimmy();
        caroline = new princess();

        //init the ground
        ground = new Ground();
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainGameLoop)

    }

private function startLevel1():void 
    {

        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainGameLoop)
        gotoAndStop("Level 1");
        addChild(character);
        character.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
        character.y = 0;
        addChild(ground);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, level1)
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
        childrenOnStage = this.numChildren;
    }

    private function processCollisions():void
    {
        trace(character.name); //said instance6 even though i set its name to..."player")
        trace(character.name == "player"); // said false for this
        trace(character.name == "instance6"); // said true for this so i put this name below 
        for (var c:int = 0; c < childrenOnStage; c++)
        {

            if (getChildAt(c).name == "instance6" || getChildAt(c).name == "enemy")
            {
```

you have seen that I have initiated my variables and declared them.

character has been given a name, "player". However this name does not apply to this since the trace commands in processCollision functions begs to differ.

However, I have kinda fixed the problem thanks to the trace commands, how ever why is the name set to player.

Answer (score 0):

fixed, silly me!

```
            character = timmy;
```

this means that character is an instance of what timmy is!

There for, when I declare and init timmy, I have to set timmy's name to "player".

```
timmy.name = "player";
```

therefore.

```
character.name will equal player, since...

character = player
```

I sure to do love the As3, the class system, and hierarchy system :)

Sorry for wasting time, this was a noobish mistake.